# I want to send Private messages to Persons with two Certain Roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So baseicly thats my code right now.

```
@bot.command()
async def message_role(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message):
    for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await member.send(message)
```

If i type role: discord.Role two times in logically its gives an error about role: discord.Role is double in.
Is there a way to disable the error? Or to write it like when i type in !message_role Test1 Test2 Hello will work. Test1 and Test2 are Roles ^^
I Would prefer a Solution hint or where i can find a solution. But i would take a whole Answer too ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add two roles as arguments

```py
@bot.command()
async def message_role(ctx, role1: discord.Role, role2: discord.Role, *, message):
    # Looping through every member in the guild
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        # Checking if the member has both roles
        if role1 in member.roles and role2 in member.roles:
            await member.send(message)
```

If you want an infinite amount of roles you can use [`commands.Greedy`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=greedy#discord.ext.commands.Greedy)

```py
@bot.command()
async def message_role(ctx, roles: commands.Greedy[discord.Role], *, message):
    # Looping through every member in the guild
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        # Checking if the member has all roles
        if all(role in member.roles for role in roles):
            await member.send(message)
```

Comment: wow am i so dumb just rename the roles to 1 and 2 wow. Thanks i never would though such simple. i Will accept the anwnser as soon as possbile.

Comment: No worries! Remember to accept the answer if it helped:)